# SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) The following From address failed:

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require("PHPMailer_5.2.4/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure= "ssl"; // Used instead of TLS when only POP mail is selected
$mail->From = "practicas8@soltel.es";
$mail->FromName = "Rafa";
$mail->Host = "smtp.serviciodecorreo.es"; // specif smtp server
$mail->Port = 465; // Used instead of 587 when only POP mail is selected
$mail->Username = "xxxxx@soltel.es"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "xxxxx"; // SMTP password
$mail->AddAddress("xxxx@soltel.es", "xxxx"); //replace myname and mypassword to yours
$mail->AddReplyTo("xxxx@soltel.es", "Soltel2019");
$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
//$mail->AddAttachment("c:\\temp\\js-bak.sql"); // add attachments
//$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/11-10-00.zip");
$mail->IsHTML(true); // establecer formato HTML
$mail->Subject = 'test';
$mail->Body = 'test';

if($mail->Send()) {echo "Send mail successfully";}
else {echo "Send mail fail";}
?>
```

Comment: Hola Rafael. Te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]! Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio. Las preguntas han de contener una explicacion de lo que tratas de hacer, de lo que has intentado hasta ahora, el problema concreto que tienes y que has investigado para resolverlo. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar la pregunta. Tener solo codigo no es claro y no podemos ayudarte.Pulsa en [edit] para mejroarla. Un saludo!

Comment: Hola Rafael, el mensaje de error es bastante descriptivo, has intentado conectarte a este smtp por medio de algun gestor de correo para verificar que los datos de conexión son correctos? Por ejemplo Thunderbird? Inténtalo ya que todo indica a que los datos son los que fallan. Saludos.

Comment: [`PHPMailer` está ya en su versión 6](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), mientras que tú sigues usando la versión `5.2`, en la cual me parece había problemas de este tipo. Convendría que actualices.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer estas desde windows, te recomiendo que uses un gestor como mail, outtlook o thunderbird para testear tu coneccion, puede que el firewall este bloqueando tu red.
si todo anda ok deveria de funcionar el codigo.